# How to compare two list and find if element from first list exist between two value of the other list

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have list of ages and agesGroups

I want to take each element of the list ages and search in list ageGroup the interval where it is to recover the price ,If an element is in two interval so we recover the lowest price of the list ,I want the sum of the total prices.

For example :

for age 8 I have price =50   and for 20 and 67 i have two choices 90 and 70 ,I will choose the lowest price which  is 70 and then the result have to be 70 + 70 + 50 = 190
price = 190

```js
let ages = [8, 20, 67]
let agesGroups = [{
    min: 10,
    max: 90,
    price: 90
  },
  {
    min: 10,
    max: 90,
    price: 70
  },
  {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    price: 50
  }
]
let price = 0
ages.forEach(a => {
  agesGroups.forEach(s => {
    if (a >= s.min && a <= s.max) {
      price = price + parseInt(s.price, 10);
    }
  })
})

console.log(price);
```

The result that i got

```
price = 140
```

Comment: You have two objects with `min = 10` and `max = 90`. So you're going to add `90` and `70` for any ages between 10 and 90.

Comment: And since you have `>=` and `<=`, you'll add all 3 prices for age == 10.

Comment: But i want to choose the lowest  between 90 and 70 which is 70

Comment: I added an example to understand better

Comment: Where in your code do you try to find the lowest matching price?

Comment: How are you getting 140? When I run your code I get 370.

Comment: here's one way to do it: Use `filter()` to find all the matching age groups. Then get all those prices and call `Math.min()` to get the lowest one. Add that to the total price.

Comment: Where i can use filter() ?

Comment: Inside the `ages.forEach()` loop, use `ageGroups.filter()`

Comment: I'm trying really hard not to write this for you, just pointing you in the general direction so you can figure it out yourself.

Comment: Really  i don't understand please, can you give me an example?

Comment: What kind of example could I give without just writing the whole thing?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes using Array methods are to restrictive of what's returned and it's difficult to navigate. A `for...of` loop is easier to read and refactor with Array methods later.

- Define `prices` array to keep each best price
- Outer `for...of` loop to iterate `ages` array

  - Define `inRange` array to keep each price within a `range`
  - Inner `for...of` loop to iterate `ranges` array

    - Determine if `age` is within range of `range.min` and `range.max`
    - Push `range.price` into `inRange` array if `age` is within range
  - Push the smallest `range.price` of `inRange` into `prices` array

    ```
    prices.push( Math.min(...inRange));
    ```
- Then add all prices of `price` array

  ```
  prices.reduce((sum, add) => sum + add)
  ```

```js
let ages=[8,20,67],ranges=[{min:10,max:90,price:90},{min:10,max:90,price:70},{min:0,max:10,price:50}];
let prices = [];

for (let age of ages) {
  let inRange = [];
  for (let range of ranges) {
    if (age >= range.min && age <= range.max) {
      inRange.push(range.price);
    }
  }
  prices.push( Math.min(...inRange));
}

let total = prices.reduce((sum, add) => sum + add);

console.log(total);
```

Refactored

```js
let ages=[8,20,67],ranges=[{min:10,max:90,price:90},{min:10,max:90,price:70},{min:0,max:10,price:50}];

let total = ages.map(age => {
  let prices = ranges.flatMap(rng => rng.min <= age && rng.max >= age ? [rng.price] : []);
  return Math.min(...prices);
  }).reduce((sum, add) => sum + add);

console.log(total)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion , It's work good 

Comment: @sokida No problem. I added a refactored version that uses `.flatMap()` as a flexible filter if you want less code.

Answer (score 1):

Solution - by the suggestion of @Barmar - using reduce(). "result" now contains minimal prices for all the ages. You can summarize them if need:

```
let result = []
ages.forEach(a => {
    result.push(agesGroups.reduce((res, s) => {
        if(a >= s.min && a <= s.max) {
            if (s.price < res) { res = s.price}
        }
        return res
    }, Infinity));
});
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Your first loop is equivalent to use `filter()`, why don't you just use that?

Comment: You are right. Followed by map(), to make sure return s.price

Comment: The second loop could be `reduce()`, not `map()`, since you just want a single price, not an array.

Comment: You don't need to write your own `min()` function, use `Math.min()`.

Comment: Math.min() doesn't seem to accept an array as input ?

Comment: `Math.min(...array)`

Comment: You are right - reduce() is the best!. No need filter().map() and even Math.min(). Posting the solution in a second ))

Comment: `agesGroups.filter(s =>  { return a >= s.min && a <= s.max }).map(el => { return el.price; })` Wondering if `.filter` and then `.map` - both may be replaced by `reduce` in one-go. How about: `agesGroups.reduce((f, i) => (a >= f.min && a <= f.max ? [...f, f.price] : f ), []);`

Comment: Yeah... I used reduce() in my latest solution (I provided 3 :)

Comment: Thank you so much for you all , It's work

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. Thanks also to the suggestions of other people here.
BTW I deleted longer solutions, keep here the shortest one.

Comment: Thank you so much sir 